# Matching three columns with different header

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Pls help in getting following . . 
Using excel 2007 - 
I need to create a column (say D) based on the values in the three columns (A,B and C) and their header. some of the rows are blank and this should come as blank in the resulting column D.

```
A       B       C       D
blank   1       blank   B
1       blank   blank   A
blank   1       blank   B
blank   blank   1       C
1       blank   blank   A
blank   1       blank   B
blank   blank   1       C
1       blank   blank   A
blank   1       blank   B
blank   blank   blank   blank
1       blank   blank   A
blank   1       blank   B
blank   blank   1       C
1       blank   blank   A
blank   1       blank   B
blank   blank   blank   blank
1       blank   blank   A
blank   blank   blank   blank
blank   blank   1       C
```

Answer (score 1):

Pleae try this..

```
=IF(AND(A2="",B2="",C2=""),"Blank",IF(A2=1,"A",IF(B2=1,"B",IF(C2=1,"C","n/a"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it worked as I wanted. What's the meaning of "n/a" in the expression and what it does while computing?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat shorter:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH(2,A2:C2),"A","B","C"),"")
```

Finds the index of the A:C columns of the cell containing the `1` and uses that index to [CHOOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) the appropriate letter for output. If all three cell are bank the [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function returns an error and this is trapped with [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) to return an empty (to appearances) cell.

IFERROR was introduced in Excel 2007. For earlier versions [ISERROR](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php) may be required, within an [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) statement - which would negate any saving in length of the formula.

The final pair of `""` may be replaced by `"blank"` if that actual word is to be visible.